# plotting convergence of genetic algorothm

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, interpolation, genetic-algorithm

I am using  genetic algorithm in MATLAB to do a two objective optimization problem. I want to know is there any way to plot the population at each generation in a 3d volume? I mean, (f1,f2,n) where f1 is the value of the first objective which i want to minimize and f2 is the value of the second objective that i want to minimize and n is the number of iteration, at the end of each iteration(generation) genetic algorithm produces a pareto-fron which is consists of  several points(f1,f2).

how do I plot a volume at the end of optimization to visualize how genetic algorithm converged to a final results? interpolating the convex hulls of each generation maybe?

Answer (score 4):

I think a 3D volume would be very hard to interpret, it would probably be best to do an animation (ideally) in 2D, or if you can't do an animation, plot all iterations on the same plot with e.g. changing color to indicate iterations.

For example: 
[image: optimization]